# How to parse useState to determine singular active class for mapped compontents?

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I'm trying to set a single `<li>` element as active on click for a single page application. I am currently parsing a function by prop to the compontent. I'd like to have a single instance of `active` for all compontents, rather than one for each. Currently I get a lot of render timeouts, I'm sure there is a way to do this.

Should I be using `useState` in the component instead?
The code for setting the class is in the sandbox link as a comment.

[Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-herschel-q3spm?file=/src/App.js)

Thanks.

Comment: Actually I don't get your point, you want to set active but on what condition? You haven't written this

Comment: Sorry, I'll add that now. Active on <li> click.

Comment: Yeah but still it's not clear enough, you want to do something with li element? Add class? Please describe more your problem

Comment: Alright, I'll be more specific. I want to toggle an 'active' class for a clicked <li> where 'active' is only present on the current/last clicked <li>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a list item to become active when clicked, you should write the following:

```
<ListItem key={item.id} handleActive={item => handleActive(item)}>
    {item.text}
</ListItem>
```

When you process actions, you always have an input value. So, you forgot to write `item =>` in your `handleActive` property.

Comment: This does solve part of my issue, I think this requires two questions, I've made some progress, you're welcome to review the sandbox which is now updated to reflect the new quesiton. Thank you for that bit!